# Generate Separate CSS files from SCSS

Tags: webpack, sass

I want to generate separate `css` files from each `scss` files.

I was considering to use `webpack` for this but couldn't find any proper configuration for that.

I want to achieve this:

```
scss/
     |
     |– utilities/
     |   |– _variables.scss
     |   |– _mixins.scss
     |   |– _root.scss
     |
     |– base/
     |   |– _reset.scss
     |   |– _fonts.scss
     |   |– _root.scss
     |
     |– blocks/
     |   |– _root.scss
     |   |– _menu.scss
     |   |– _hero.scss
     |   |– _news_block.scss
     |   |– _root.scss
     |
     – _main.scss

css/
     |
     |– utilities/
     |   |– variables.css
     |
     |– base/
     |   |– reset.css
     |   |– fonts.css
     |
     |– blocks/
         |– menu.css
         |– hero.css
         |– news_block.css

index.html
```

There are `mixins.scss` for various `scss` functions.  Also `root.scss` files include all `scss` files in its directory.

This is my `webpack.config.js` but when I start `npm start` it gives various errors:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './scss/main.scss',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/main.css',
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To save CSS into separate files you should define separate entrypoint for each CSS file.

> Note: one entrypoint -> one generated CSS file

The generated CSS files will be saved into the directory defined in `output.path` option, e.g. `dist/`.

There is the example of the `entry` option for your use case:

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  entry: {
    // entry key is the output filename (w/o extension) relative to the `output.path` (dist/)
    'utilities/variables': './scss/utilities/variables.scss', // => dist/css/utilities/variables.css
    'base/reset': './scss/base/reset.scss', // => dist/css/base/reset.css
    'base/fonts': './scss/base/fonts.scss',
    'blocks/menu': './scss/blocks/menu.scss',
    'blocks/hero': './scss/blocks/hero.scss',
    'blocks/news_block': './scss/blocks/news_block.scss',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // save CSS files into dist/css/ dir under the output filename defined as entry key
      filename: 'css/[name].css', // use the substitution `[name]`
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
  },
};
```